# XSLT 2 - encapsulate a known list of words in a para

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

```
<CanYouSpanMatches>
      <possMatch>
         <pillME>black cat</pillME>
         <pillME>brown dog</pillME>
         <pillME>tree</pillME>
      </possMatch>
      
      <property_description>A black cat was chased around a large tree by a brown dog
      </property_description>
</CanYouSpanMatches>
```

Using XSLT 2 how can I "encapsulate " all  the strings (possMatch/pillME) with a span in the <property_description> element?

I have generated the XML  into a variable $var1 but an struggling to add the spans

I thought that tokenize() might work but the black cat don't have an obvious delimiter.

My desired results are:

```
  <property_description>A <span>black cat</span> was chased around a large <span>tree</span> by a <span>brown dog</span>
  </property_description>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Look into `xsl:analyze-string`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`xsl:analyze-string`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-analyze-string) and generate a `|` delimited regex with each of the `pillME` values in a template matching the `property_description/text()` using [`string-join()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-3/#func-string-join).

`xsl:matching-substring` is where you can wrap with `span`, and `xsl:non-matching-substring` just return the unmatched value:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="CanYouSpanMatches/property_description"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="property_description/text()">
      <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="{string-join(/CanYouSpanMatches/possMatch/pillME, '|')}">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
          <span><xsl:sequence select="."/></span>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
          <xsl:sequence select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Great idea! I was going to suggest a recursive function, but this is much more elegant.

Comment: For the provided sample data it is not needed but in general running the terms through http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_escape-for-regex.html might be necessary e.g. `string-join(/CanYouSpanMatches/possMatch/pillME/functc:escape-for-regex(.), '|')`.

Comment: Thanks Mads, this worked really well for me.  I must admit I really don't understand how it works but work it does!

I'll pop this into my toolbox for the future.

Can I ask one follow up question please.
If this was the list
<possMatch>
         <pillME type="animal">black cat</pillME>
         <pillME type="animal">brown dog</pillME>
         <pillME type="plant">tree</pillME>
      </possMatch>

I wouldn't be able to access the @type as analyse-string is now working on Atomic types?  Is there a way I could in a single pass?

Comment: Similar to how an XPath was used to generate the regex from the `pillME`, you could use the matched value within the `xsl:matching-substring` to again XPath to the `pillME` with that value and select it's attribute. `